# debugging ply in p_error() to access parser state/stack

Tags: python, parsing, ply

Is there a way to access the parser state/stack in p_error()?

All I know is that I can look at the offending token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `debug=1` to `parse` when you call it and it will output the parser stack.

Here is the function definition for that, for convenience:

`def parse(self,input=None,lexer=None,debug=0,tracking=0,tokenfunc=None):`

You can send the debugging output to a file too, if you set it up when you call `yacc`. Here is that function definition, for convenience:

`def yacc(method='LALR', debug=yaccdebug, module=None, tabmodule=tab_module, start=None, check_recursion=1, optimize=0, write_tables=1, debugfile=debug_file,outputdir='', debuglog=None, errorlog = None, picklefile=None):`

You may find it useful to checkout the `yacc` and `parse` methods in `yacc.py` to see how this works.

Answer (score 5):

If you're only interested in the stack state at the point where p_error gets triggered, but don't wish to log all the other debug info, this does a nice job:

```
def p_error(p):

    # get formatted representation of stack
    stack_state_str = ' '.join([symbol.type for symbol in parser.symstack][1:])

    print('Syntax error in input! Parser State:{} {} . {}'
          .format(parser.state,
                  stack_state_str,
                  p))
```

The `parser` you create with `parser = yacc.yacc()` must be in scope for this solution to work.

Comment: I first moved p_error definition after the yacc.yacc() call, but then p_error was not used by the yacc.yacc() call. The solution was to add "global parser" as first line of method p_error(p) and - voila - it works!